# Contextual Menu to a Specific Folder

Tags: shell-extensions

I have read how to add a contextual menu though registry to all files or files according the extension.
But how can I add a contextual menu that will work ONLY on files of a specific folder (for example on files of folder C:\contmenu)?

Can this be done?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're implementing a context menu shell extension, you get the path of the item in your [IShellExtInit::Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775094.aspx)() method. Then you can decide depending on the path whether to add your entries to the context menu or not.

It's not possible to register an extension just for a specific path though.