# How add context menu item to Windows Explorer for folders

Tags: contextmenu, explorer, windows-shell-extension-menu

I have found out how to add right-click context menu items to files on Windows Explorer, by adding keys to the registry. I.e. I can right-click on a file in Explorer and run a custom app against that file.

I would like to do the same for a folder and have not found a way to do that (yet). I see articles on creating/writing custom context menu handlers, but I would rather not go there.

I have found an article [here](http://www.askvg.com/add-cascading-menus-for-your-favorite-programs-in-windows-7-desktop-context-menu/) on how to add cascading context menu items to the Desktop and to the "Computer" in Explorer, but this does not work for any folder.

I would like to be able to add my custom app to the context menu and have it work on both files and folders. Is there a way to do this without writing a context menu handler?

---

I found the solution in the below article, which describes how to do this via the registry for files, as well as for folders:

- [How to Add Any Application Shortcut to Windows Explorer’s Context Menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/)

The following two articles provided additional info and options:

- [Ultimate Tutorial to Customize Desktop Context Menu in Windows Vista, 7 and 8](http://www.askvg.com/ultimate-tutorial-to-customize-desktop-context-menu-in-windows-vista-server-2008-and-windows-7/)
- [Add Cascading Menus for Your Favorite Programs in Windows 7 Desktop and My Computer Context Menus](http://www.askvg.com/add-cascading-menus-for-your-favorite-programs-in-windows-7-desktop-context-menu/)

Answer (score 319):

In the registry editor (`regedit.exe`) find:

### Right click on BACKGROUND of right panel

1. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` if you are administrator
2. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\Background\shell`  if you are a normal user

### Right click on FOLDER ICON in left/right panel of Windows Explorer

1. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell` if you are administrator
2. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\shell`  if you are a normal user

### Right click on file

1. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` if you are administrator
2. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\*\shell` if you are a normal user

[image: screenshots]

In all cases:

1. add a new key under `shell`, naming it as you want to name the
   context menu item
2. add a new key inside this key, named `command` (mandatory name)
3. edit the `default` property in `command` to
   `myprogrampath\path\path\executable.exe "%1"` to pass the file path and
   name of the selected file to your custom program (for `.../Directory/Background` and `.../directory/Background` cases use `%V` instead of `%1`)

---

More customization:

- **Add icon**: add a string value named `icon` for key created at step 1 with value matching an icon resource path. You can also provide an integer arguments to specify which icon to use. Example: `%SystemRoot%\System32\shell32.dll,3`
- **Display only on shift-click**: add an empty string value named `Extended` for key created at step 1
- **Customize menu entry label**: change the value of default value for key created at step 1
- **Change menu entry location**: add a string value named `Position` with one of: `Top`, `Bottom`

Comment: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` can only affect right click on background of a directory

Comment: Should be `"%1"` in case path has spaces.

Comment: When are these supposed to take effect? Do they require a restart?

Comment: immediately. There isn't even need to open a new explorer window: new settings are loaded as soon as you right-click.

Comment: seems environment variables do not work in `Command`, do they?

Comment: Yes, they're usually temporary and local to cmd windows. There was a specific panel of options to permanently add/edit env variable in winxp and win8.

Comment: Thanks. This is so helpful for me. It was hard to find a good explained answer on the internet.

Comment: When I add the `%1`, I get an error dialog `This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.` Removing the `%1` gets rid of the error dialog and launches my app, but does not pass any arguments to my app. Any advice?

Comment: Regarding my previous comment: The problem can be fixed by replacing `%1` by `%V`.

Comment: @jumpjack This did not appear to be the case for me. I had to close my explorer window and open a new one.

Comment: What if I select multiple files? How do I change(add to) the list then? `shell` doesn't work.

Comment: @akinuri I don't understand the question

Comment: Microsoft itself has pretty good documentation with a lot of examples https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/context-menu-handlers

Comment: @MichaelHerrmann Besides '%V', adding '.' also helps if you are dealing with a directory.

Comment: I was having trouble getting the icon to work until I saw this tip "icon & position string keys are not created in command, but its parent: whatever you called your app key in `\shell`" at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27090678/470749

Comment: In administrator mode: I prefer setting keys to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\*` instead of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*` (same for `Directory` etc.). The effect is the same but it's more obvious what's happening, IMHO.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to have an item appear in the context menu when you right click within an Explorer window, so within a directory and not on a specific file or directory. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: The answer is updated corresponding to comments about quotes around `%1` and `%V` for `.../Directory/Background` and `.../directory/Background` cases

Comment: Unfortunately, in Windows 11, adding to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes doesn't work: after you selected the added menu item, all changes are automatically removed. I was experimenting with it, and for specific program the item stayed after some manipulations. I cannot reproduce it for similar program. Adding to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT worked.

Comment: Also, anything related to file context menu, may not work even on Windows 10 after some update. I can reliably add the "double-click" action, changing the "UserChoice" registry key, but that is not what I was looking for. Preferable way at "double-click" would be to open the dialog, asking, which program to use, with your choice at the top. For some reason, Microsoft made a big secret around it.

Comment: The registry key you wrote for the right panel is the key for the left panel and viceversa.

Comment: @Canovas It's a little more complicated, added screenshot feom Windows 11

Comment: Adding an & marks the following character to be used as keyboard shortcut (But it doesn't seem to work when inserted as the first character.)

Comment: Following what @Amos said: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` works for background of a directory. If you navigate to a directory via Library, this does not count as a directory, but as a library. Use `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell` in that case.

Answer (score 20):

Found a cleaner, easier and faster solution: create a text file, fill it with these contents, update it to your needs, save with .reg suffix and launch it (it does not need administrator priviliges because it accesses user-part of the registry):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Setup context menu item for click on right panel:
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\Background\shell\MenuItemNameBackground\command]
@="C:\\yourpath\\executable.exe \"%1\""

; Optional: specify an icon for the item:   
; HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\Background\shell\MenuItemNameBackground]
;"icon"="C:\\yourpath\\appicon.ico"

; Optional: specify a position in the menu
; HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\Background\shell\MenuItemNameBackground]
;"position"="Bottom"

; -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

; Setup context menu item for click on folders tree item:
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\shell\MenuItemNamePanel\command]
@="C:\\yourpath\\executable.exe \"%1\""

; Optional: specify an icon for the item:   
; [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\shell\MenuItemNamePanel]
;"icon"="C:\\yourpath\\appicon.ico"

; Optional: specify a position in the menu
; [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\directory\shell\MenuItemNamePanel]
;"position"="Top"
```

In this way you can also have a backup of your configuration: just save the .reg file in a safe place. If you manually edit the registry after launching the file, right-click and slect "export".

Beware of double backspaces in path: \\

Comment: What part are we replacing?  Just `MenuItemName` or `MenuItemNameBackground`?

Comment: %1 works only for left panel on my Windows 10, for right panel, I use %V instead.

Answer (score 12):

I went back and also answered this in another [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38228006/3911065) since there doesn't appear to be much on this question specifically.

I found the simplest way was to add a String Value to the key called "AppliesTo" and set its value to "under:{path}"

In my example, I want it to only look in the T Drive, so my String value is "AppliesTo":"under:T:".

In C#, this is easily accomplished with the following:

```
RegistryKey _key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("Folder\\Shell", true);
RegistryKey newkey = _key.CreateSubKey("My Menu Item");
newkey.SetValue("AppliesTo", "under:T:");

RegistryKey subNewkey = newkey.CreateSubKey("Command");
subNewkey.SetValue("", "C:\\yourApplication.exe");
subNewkey.Close();

newkey.Close();
_key.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks for providing sample code for doing this via C#. It's a small help for anyone who wants to do this quickly from an app.

Comment: Unfortunately, the "AppliesTo" value doesn't seem to have any effect on a "Directory\Background" entry.  Does anyone know how similar limiting can be accomplished for right clicking on a folder's background?

Answer (score 6):

The only good solution I found a really working is : https://superuser.com/questions/1097054/shell-context-menu-registry-extension-doesnt-work-when-default-program-is-other

Add keys in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\**your.extension**\shell\command
Modify the last key with the command you wanna do.

For my purpose it was :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GPSBabel\gpsbabel.exe" -r -i gpx -f "%1" -x simplify,count=1000 -o gpx -F "%1.gpx"
```

If I export the it I get a .reg :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.gpx\shell\Simplify gpx\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GPSBabel\\gpsbabel.exe\" -r -i gpx -f \"%1\" -x simplify,count=1000 -o gpx -F \"%1.gpx\""
```

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt [run as administrator] and execute this command

```
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Refi2\command" /d "powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'"
```

- -d : value to execute[app name exe].
- -v : creates a new subkey inside the command key.
- -f : to forcefully override the key if already exists.
- **powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'** instead of this you can specify path of **your exe**.

For more details about more features run:-

```
reg add /?
```