# Git context menu change? Where is git commit, etc

Tags: git, contextmenu, commit

If I remember right you could choose in the installation process of git for Windows you could choose `Git GUI` and `Git Bash` or a intelligent context menu which offers you `git commit` for example.

Since I miss `git commit` in the context menu I tried reinstalling GIT but there is no such option any more.

Was it removed / Is it possible to get `git commit` in the context menu in case the Explorer shows a folders within a git repo?

Comment: What is with TortoiseGit? That implements you the context Menu and some other functions.

Comment: Yes I know. But the installation is not lean then any more and I like Git Gui/Bash in combination with Meld.

Answer (score 1):

If Git is no longer adding the context menu items that you want during installation, then you could just [add them yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29769228/1227469), using the relevant Git commands.

If you're not sure what commands to use then install a previous version of Git, note the commands, then uninstall and use them with the latest version.

Comment: Interesting work around - not sure which git version to use to get the commands. It would also be interesting why they do not offer it any more