# How to add a shortcut menu in explorer for an application/.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry, explorer

I have tried to understand [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144093(v=vs.85).aspx#register) article, but I failed to get what I wanted.

I want to add a shortcut menu (preferably via a registry entry) to the rightclick menu in the windows explorer, when the rightclick occures onto a **registered file for my application**.

Just like ms word, I want to have a **new** and a **open** menu entry in the context menu.

Now afaik, this is called [verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175(v=vs.85).aspx) and I found them in the windows registry for word, but I don't get how they are added. What exactly do I have to add to my registry key?

And is there a known way to do this with built-in c#/.NET functionality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How add context menu item to Windows Explorer for folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders)

Comment: @etalon11 no, because I want the menu entry only to show up when the rightclick occures onto a file of a given type