# Programmatically add own program to the context menu for files in a zip archive

Tags: c#, c++, windows, zip

This question applies to Windows operating system and the programming language C++ or C#.

In the Windows File Explorer: When I click on a zip archive I can see its file contents. When I right-click on one of these files, I see a context menu with the options: `Open|Cut|Copy|Delete|Properties`.

What do I have to do to register my program in this context menu?

When my program is called then I would like to open that file with it. I have code that adds my program to the normal file context menu of the windows file explorer and I have code to get data from a zip archive. The missing part is the user to enable to choose my application to start for a zipped file.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders

Comment: I don't think so. My application is already registered as shell extension for all files types and folders. But it does not show up in the context menu of files in the zip archive. Also no other application is displayed. I believe that the existence of the context menu items of a file in the zip archive is somehow determined by the zip program. The question is if and how I can add my program to it.

Comment: I suspect this isn't possible. Do you know of *any* application that modifies the context menu for the Compressed Folder contents? If you do, than perhaps check the registry for relevant hooks. If not, then well...

Comment: No, I don't know of any of such program. My hope was that an expert here can explain how the context menu for zipped files works and can shine a light on the way to do it for an own program.