# Why isn't there a "Git Init Here" option on my right-click box?

Tags: git, git-for-windows

I'm trying to start learning `git` and use it. I've downloaded a training video about `git` and am currently watching it.

I've downloaded and installed `git` on my computer. I use Windows 8 OS (32 bit version). But I don't know why I don't have a `Git Init Here` option when I right-click:

[image]

As you see, the box that comes up when I right-click has 2 options about git:

- `Git GUI Here`
- `Git Bash Here`

But the one in the tutorial video has one more option named `Git Init Here`. Well, why mine doesn't have that option? Did I install the `git`  wrongly?

Comment: Downvoter please leave a comment and explain what's wrong with my question?

Comment: What video are you watching?  Are you sure it refers to your particular OS version?  How did you install Git? What version?

Comment: Do you have write permissions in the current directory?

Comment: I use `git version 2.11.0.windows.1` ..! And no, I'm not sure my OS and the one on the video are exactly the same, is it important? Also I've installed Git by downloading it from [here](https://git-scm.com/download/) *(windows)* and pressing some *next*s.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add this information?  I don't know if it matters: I don't know enough to answer your question, I just came here because it had the [r] tag.  But providing this information will help you get upvoted and help people with the relevant expertise answer your question ...

Comment: @BenBolker Honestly I'm pretty much newbie in Git and I don't know what's *permissions*  ..! All I want to know, is that option *(which I don't have it)* a vital option?

Comment: @BenBolker Ah I see. ok thank you

Comment: by "permissions" I mean permission (from the OS) to create files in that directory -- not specifically anything having to do with Git.

Comment: FYI, if you are using Windows 11, there's a post created for that. You can track that availability there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70237709/how-to-add-a-git-bash-here-context-menu-option-to-the-windows-explorer-in-wind

Answer (score 3):

This menu item (and more) used to be [in git-cheetah plugin](https://github.com/msysgit/Git-Cheetah/blob/master/common/cheetahmenu.c#L387) which was included in the older "msysgit" git build. Its successor Git For Windows does not have it. If you miss the command you can set it up yourself as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29769228/2303202) or install additional product which provides them, for example TortoiseGit or GitExtensions.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to clear that <kbd>Git Init Here</kbd> just creates a hidden file named `.git`. Second, <kbd>Git GUI Here</kbd> opens the Git GUI and then you can create a new repository, choose your file and create a file named `.git`. So there is no difference between using <kbd>Git Init Here</kbd> and <kbd>Git GUI Here</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

The git-cheetah plugin was installed based on older git installation options.
Select the "Git Bash Here" option from the context menu and at the prompt type "git init".

Answer (score -1):

It should not give issue, please confirm whether git is installed properly or not by echoing the PATH;

If yes then please try once by restarting your system, sometimes it doesn't take effect until we restart our system.

For better understanding of git you may refer [here](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1), a very interactive session where you can track your progress.