# How to add "git status" command to Windows Explorer context menu for folder?

Tags: git, windows-explorer

I have Tortoise Git, but it works much slower than calling "git status". I wrote the batch file:

```
cd /d %1
git status
pause
exit
```

According to this question [How add context menu item to Windows Explorer for folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders)
I try to add command as

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K "C:\BATs\ShowGitStatus.bat %1"
```

But I get the "The file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. ..." What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Batch file should be directly runnable. Why do you need the `cmd /k`?

Comment: Just to be sure, you name your batch file `ShowGitStatus.bat` in that folder? You tried running the command in `cmd` and it works?

Comment: I guess the `"`s in `%1` messes up the existing `"`. Didn't try, so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add new Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\GitStatus key in the
   registry
2. Add new Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\GitStatus\Command key
3. Change the default value of the last key to
   `C:\BATs\ShowGitStatus.bat %1`
4. Place listed in question bat file tho the C:\BATs\ folder. Name it ShowGitStatus.bat

This should work.