# Reading Thunderbird "mozMapi32_InUse.dll" source code

Tags: java, c#, c++, c, thunderbird

As you probably know thunderbird is an open-source email client. I'm trying to read their mozMapi32_InUse.dll source code, but I can't find it anywhere on their page. They use it for receiving email data from the Windows API, using that data they fill out their email interface.

**My goal is to build an application that will receive file path if a user on Windows does right-click to file --> Send to ---> Mail Recipient**
**In this action, my application needs to receive that file path.**

Mozilla Thunderbird does the same thing using their custom dll mozMapi32_InUse.dll and I'm interested to see how I can do the same.

Comment: Besides the Microsoft MAPI documentation, there must be several thousand (if not tens of thousands) of examples on how to use the MAPI. Not to mention that there are many other libraries and frameworks which have support for sending emails programmatically. What else have you searched for? Why do you focus just on the Thunderbird component? It's very likely that the Mozilla Thunderbird code is very complex, and probably not a good example for beginners (or even advanced) programmers.

Comment: tag spamming is bad, please don't do this way

Comment: Also, you don't need any code for this. What are you looking for is fully controlable with windows registry magic. Just google a little for something like "add item to windows right click" (look for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29769228/2716623))

Comment: @vasily.sib Right click was just an example, it needs to work from any app that has an option Send as Email. My app would simply catch the attachment file path and process it.