# Get windows explorer current selected files to unity

Tags: c#, .net, windows, unity-game-engine

**Question:**

Is there a way to get the windows explorer current selected files absolute paths as a string array via C# within Unity engine ?

**Goal:**

On pressing a shortcut key - to get an array of absolute paths for the current selected files - then to be sent via tcp socket connection to another local device.

**Details:**

Current active window can be fetched via LazoCoder's WinApi-Wrapper ( https://github.com/LazoCoder/WinAPI-Wrapper ). The question remains on how to cycle thru the displayed files while checking if they're selected or not ?

**Notes:**
The project is developed in Unity game engine.

Thank you in advance,

~Ray

Comment: Why not use some drag-and-drop logic or just open an file chooser dialog? Seams like a very strange feature. It might be also worth implementing some context-menu-add-on for the windows-explorer like NotePad++ or WinMerge have.

Comment: @Ackdari Drag and drop doesn't work if run as administrator (win os bug). Context-menu-add-on for the windows-explorer might actually be a good option, do you happen to have some references on how to implement this ?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29769228/6560579) for adding context-menu entries

Comment: @Ackdari thnx for the link ;)