# vs-code: How to open current WSL folder *as wsl* from command line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

How do I do this in my non-vs-code terminal:

```
wsl:/home/peter/myproject$ code .
```

and then have `myproject` open in Visual Studio Code *in a new WSL window* or somehow in WSL mode?

I *am* able to open the current folder as a "normal" windows folder using:

```
"$(wslpath 'C:\Users\pvm\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe')" .
```

but then many things don't work, because it isn't opened as a WSL folder. I can however, click on where the red arrow points, and then on where the green arrow points.

[image: code screenshot for reopen folder in wsl]

As an alternative, I can open a WSL window in VS Code, and open a terminal from there. From inside this terminal-in-code, I can navigate to a folder and type `code .`. Then it gets opened exactly as I want, but this is only possible from a terminal-in-code, not from a standalone "normal" WSL terminal. If one tries to run the same code command from a normal terminal, one gets a "Command is only available in WSL or inside a Visual Studio Code terminal." error. And this is [as designed](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1042).

So the question remains: How do I open a folder from a standalone WSL terminal in VS code in WSL mode?

Comment: Opening VS Code and using the terminal there to open further WSL VS Code instances has been my workflow, but it feels rather awkward. Very interested if there is a better way :)

Comment: I am quite curious about the subject as I need a command line solutio for this as I need to do this while testing some vscode extensions (automation). Have you found a way to start code and open a folder in wsl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[VS Code can be started with the `--remote` command line parameter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl#_open-a-remote-folder-or-workspace):

```
code --remote wsl+<distro name> <path in WSL>
```

For your example:

```
"$(wslpath 'C:\Users\pvm\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe')" --remote wsl+<distro name> "$(pwd)"
```

I added an `alias` to my `.bashrc` to open VS Code in the current working directory:

```
alias c="code --remote wsl+ubuntu \"\$(pwd)\""
```

Comment: Thankfully I'm no longer using Windows, so I have no idea if this works. If people comment that it works mentioning me, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Check wsl distros in Powershell with `wsl -l`.  I'm using Ubuntu-20.04.  This did the trick `code --remote wsl+Ubuntu-20.04 /home/me/git/project`
@PeterV.Mørch

Comment: Hi, anyone knows how to open folder in wsl extension workspace same as this question by double clicking in explorer?

Comment: @Shashank Bhatt I would try: 1. [find registry key](https://superuser.com/a/1378291) 2. Add `--remote wsl+<distro name>` to the registry key value (no quotation marks) 3. Find some way to change `"%1"` (file path argument) to the corresponding WSL paths. 
Other idea: [Add a context menu item to the Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29769228). Isn't exactly what you want, but may be useful.