# How to remove default context menu items when a specific folder is right clicked in win10 registry

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I'm trying to remove all the default context menu items when folders with specific icon are right clicked in win 10 registry, not a third party service.

How to do that?

Please help me with exact solutions.

Anyone who knows the solution using C#, .NET framework would be more helpful. But for now I am trying to do that with registry first.

Thank you so much

I don't know where I can start from.

Comment: Start from related topics, e.g. [how to add context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20449316/1997232).

Comment: You may want to learn about *shell extensions*, [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174369/How-to-Write-Windows-Shell-Extension-with-NET-Lang) is a nice tutorial.