# Adding shell context menu entries for files matching specific conditions

Tags: c#, shell, registry, tortoisesvn, shell-extensions

I developed a .NET 4 application providing custom features for Subversion working copies. Like for the TortoiseSVN software I'd like to show shell context menu entries only for files located in Subversion working copies. These directories can be identified by an hidden '.svn' folder stored at their root.

The best solution seem to write a context menu shell extension, and getting the path of the file in the IShellExtInit::Initialize() method like proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686411/create-windows-right-click-context-menu-for-specific-folders). I am not familiar with C++ and doing it with C# [doesn't seem good](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/22/10396079.aspx), even if [some nice examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/512956/NET-Shell-Extensions-Shell-Context-Menus) exist, and I don't want to chose a complicated and time-consuming solution.

I also found that the Advanced Query Syntax (AQS) can be used in registry values to [evaluate a condition before showing a context menu entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171%28VS.85%29.aspx#dynamic_behavior), but I can't find examples to look if a parent folder contains a '.svn' directory.

Can you please help me to find a simple solution to my problem?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks context menu shell extension is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Denis. I think that I'm going to try doing it with [SharpShell](https://sharpshell.codeplex.com), even if it is not recommended to use .NET it seems so easy to implement. I will check if the context menu takes time to load.