# How do you debug context menu handlers?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

I am trying to work on a [context menu handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024597/context-menu-handler-for-folders) following the [app sample from Microsoft](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppShellExtContextMenuHandl-410a709a/view/SourceCode), but I am having difficulties because I am not sure how to **debug** it? How do you normally debug an MSVC++ context menu handler in Visual Studio so that you can step through the logic of it? I have tried looking online but I couldn't find anything that helps. Is there any way to make it request the debugger like there is in the .NET world?

Comment: I've never written one, but I'd assume you debug it the same way you debug any other shell extension. Launch Explorer, and then attach the debugger to that process.

Comment: Use `::DebugBreak()` in the context handler to cause a break into the debugger.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @CodyGray OMG why didn't I think of that?! Yes, that makes sense; thank you, it worked.

Comment: @RichardCritten Ah, even better. You guys are champs!